# Google Chrome Plugin development - Monitor network requests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to monitor network traffic with a google chrome plugin for the local page? For example, I want to monitor every time a web page requests a specific file (based on regex match), and if a user clicks the plugin, it opens a new tab to that file.

Comment: Local meaning `file://`?

Comment: no, for example, i can see in the developer tab, a page loads http://somesite.com/somemp3.mp3, and any time that happens, i want to be able to download that mp3 by clicking the button, which opens a new tab, pointing to that link...

Comment: Also see   http://stackoverflow.com/q/7819463/632951 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6831916/632951

Answer (score 4):

The "proper" way would be to use [webRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.webRequest.html), but it is still experimental:

```
//background.html
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log("resource", details.url);
});
```

Meanwhile you can catch resources that are loading with the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("beforeload", function(event) {
    console.log("resource", event.url);
}, true);
```

This needs to go into a content script that runs with `"run_at": "document_start"`.

Comment: it looks like that is working, and able to find the base requests, but it seems like these files are being pulled via a GET in an SWF... any way of getting around that?

Comment: @wuntee `beforeload` is the only method that I know, all other involve experimental api (and I am not sure if even that would work with flash).

Comment: hmm... thanks for the help. its frustrating because i can see in the 'Network'  tab of the developer pane, them being transmitted... assuming that pane has more privileges than an extension.

Comment: @wuntee If you see it then experimental api should be able to catch it, in theory. There is no stable api that can access resources panel.

Comment: @serg, Is it still experimental?