# Read/Intercept HTTP response body Using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to intercept http response body without using chrome debugger as mentioned here ?

[Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939467/chrome-extension-to-read-http-response)

and here

[Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534771/chrome-extension-how-to-get-http-response-body)

Thanks,

Comment: probably chrome.socket API?

Comment: No, there's no other way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished`

Answer (score -2):

In network tab of developer tool.
When you select a request on network tab on right hand side yoi will get tabs like request header, response header, and many other.. out of which on os for response data.

Use the chrome.webRequest API to intercept, block, or modify requests in-flight.

[chrome.webRequest Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

Comment: I'm trying to develop a Chrome Plugin which can read / intercept response body.