# use chrome.webRequest api to monitor the download request, but tabid is -1, how can i get correct tabid?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download, tabs, webrequest

i want to build a chrome extension, download some file one by one, so i need pair the download file and the tabid that fire the download.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (e) {
    log("onBeforeRequest:", JSON.stringify(e));
}, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, []);
```

use this code i can get the url, but can't get the tabid. the tabid is -1 allways, 
then, how can i get the correct tabid or how can i pair the download and the tabid?

fyi, i can't get `<a>` or href, i just mock click() event one by one.

Comment: This is a limitation of the API so you'll have to find a workaround.

Comment: @wOxxOm, so how can i do it?

Comment: I guess you'll have to intercept everything that may cause a download in your content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm my contentscript make click(), and then download a file, but, from background, i can not make sure one download is fired by my contentscript. my target is just make the download one by one, because if i click them all at one time, only the last one will be download.

Comment: @wOxxOm so  i know that my click make the download, but when user click multi time my extension on different web page, i can not distinguish that, although i can intercept everything that cause a download. can you give me a idea?

Comment: It depends on how exactly that page starts the download. My idea was to use a standard DOM method like an event listener or intercept something used by the site in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm, let me think about it, we add an right event listener, and know onepage download a file, but wen user download a lot of files from many pages, how can i know witch download is relate with witch page? or you mean by url? if by url, the question is how can i get a ajax download url?

Comment: Example: [Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134114)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you very much. i will learn it. :)