# Is it possible to build a chrome extension that will look for a specific js network request and pull data from it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build an extension that will monitor the network requests of a given website, wait for a specific js file to be requested, then pull some data from it. Or would it be possible to ditch the extension idea and build an application that can web scrape from the network requests instead?

Comment: Extensions can do it, but you should provide more info about that network request ([MCVE](/help/mcve)).

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry that's my bad. I do not have too much knowledge on the matter but I can explain more of what I am trying to do. When I go into DevTools > Network on a website, there is a file that pops up and the request URL is to googleapis, the method is GET and the file is java script. When I preview the js file there is some data in it that I would like to scrape every time a new request is sent. Was wondering how I could achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939467/chrome-extension-to-read-http-response)