# Fetch event never gets triggered in Chrome extension service worker. Is this expected?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, service-worker-events

#### What I want to do

I'm trying to intercept a third party website's fetch events and modify its request body in a Chrome extension. Modifying the request body is not allowed by the [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest) event handler. But it looks like regular service workers do have the ability to [listen for and modify fetch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope#fetch) and manually respond to the request using my own response, which means I should be able to intercept the request, modify the body, send the modified request to the API, and then respond to the original request with my modified request's response.

#### The problem

It looks like neither of these event handlers ever get triggered, despite plenty of fetch events being triggered by the website, as I can see in the Network panel.

```js
// background.js

self.onfetch = (event) => console.log(event.request); // never shows

// or

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  console.log(event.request); // never shows
});
```

I can verify that the service worker is running by seeing other `console.log`s appearing in the service worker console, both top-level logs as well as logs triggered by the `"install"` event

```js
// background.js

console.log(self); // works

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log(event); // works
});
```

#### Hypothesis

Do the fetch event handlers not get triggered because extension service workers are not allowed access to these for security reasons? That would make sense, I just haven't seen this documented anywhere explicitly so it would be good to know if this is indeed a platform limitation or if I'm doing something wrong.

#### Alternate solutions?

If this is indeed a limitation of the extensions platform, is there *any* way other way I can use a Chrome extension to modify request bodies on a third party website?

Comment: The fetch event of your extension's service worker is only for urls like chrome-extension://your-ext-id which is not related to the web pages. The solutions can be adapted from those listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8939467) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18534771) (there may be better examples though).

Comment: I'm looking to modify the request body, not read the response

Comment: Yes, as I noted, these examples can be adapted. The approach is the same.

Comment: IIRC, xhook.js library offers all of that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those don't work when used in Chrome extensions. I tried monkeypatching `window.fetch` - which appears to be how xhook.js works - from both content scripts and service workers and nothing happened

Comment: Those examples are explicitly made to work in chrome extensions. To use xhook.js you need to run it in the [page context](/a/9517879) (aka "main world") similarly to the examples.

Comment: Is fetch event handler invoked for the same origin requests?