# Intercepting POST request in chrome extension, how do it properly?

Tags: javascript, networking, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to intercept POST request made by the website and intercept the response but somehow I am not getting the correct result.

I'm trying this same on Facebook ads library and trying to fetch the response body, I can see the POST request made by checking the "Network tab" in the browser. I want to fetch those responses within the code and then save it for later use.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    if (details.method == "POST")
      // Use this to decode the body of your post
      var postedString = decodeURIComponent(
        String.fromCharCode.apply(
          null,
          new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)
        )
      );
    console.log(postedString);
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["requestBody"]
);
```

That's what I have written/checked from stackoverflow so far.

Comment: "I am not getting the correct result." --- What is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Comment: Actual result is the payload of data in facebook ads library webpage like each ad detail but what I am getting is "undefined", It's because I am not fetching any POST method, if I change the if condition to "GET" I will get tons of request like 300 but no POST request, even in networking tab I see post request being made.
For Get method, I am also not able to parse the body or see the response.

Comment: Your code intercepts request body not response body. Note that GET requests don't have any request body. Again, request body is not response body. See [Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8939467) +
[Chrome Extension - How to get HTTP Response Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18534771) +
[Modify HTTP responses from a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18310484).

Comment: @wOxxOm Those posts are outdated and works for manifest version 2, is it possible to have anything for manifest version 3?

Comment: The approach is still the same.