# Can one intercept JSON response using declarativeNetRequest in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I want to read the JSON returned by some XHR requests on a particular website. Is this possible with the new manifest version 3 for Chrome Extensions?

In that case, how does one accomplish it with declarativeNetRequest or similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension to read HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939467/chrome-extension-to-read-http-response) There are also limited solutions [here](/q/8939467) and re-fetching the URL directly. There's no way to use declarativeNetRequest for this.

Comment: Thank you, what I don't get is how to capture the Reponse from injected.js here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134114/104059

I can see that it changes the XHR.prototype but do I need to dispatch an event, or how would my content-scripts be able to make use of the HTTP Response data?

Comment: Yes, send a CustomEvent, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198).