# WebExtensions : Can you access a JSON object that was fetched by the webpage

Tags: json, resources, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way **after** a webpage has loaded to access a JSON object that was fetched by the webpage?

I am aware that I could use the **webRequest api** to get the url of the JSON resource and fetch it again but i'd like to know if there's a way to access it without re-downloading?

Can I hook into the pages javascript or is there a better way?

This might seem unnecessary given I could just re-download but that doesn't feel very elegant to me.

I have googled for a while but can't find much. A steer in the right direction would be appreciated.

I am using Firefox

Comment: In Firefox you should be able to do it directly via [browser.webRequest.filterResponseData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData) in the background script or via wrappedJSObject in the content script ([example](/a/64817357)). In Chrome it's not that simple: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134114).

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario the JSON data I wish to access is loaded by an **xmlhttprequest**

Capturing such a JSON resource can be simply achieved with Firefox by capturing the http response using **browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener** and then filtering the response within the listener using **browser.webRequest.filterResponseData**

Given that JSON files can be quite large the following is a minimal example built upon the generic example found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter/ondata).

background.js

```
function listener(details) {
    const filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
    const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  
    const data = [];
    filter.ondata = (event) => {
      data.push(event.data);
    };
  
    filter.onstop = (event) => {
      let jsonStr = "";

      if (data.length === 1) {
        jsonStr = decoder.decode(data[0]);
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          const stream = i !== data.length - 1;
          jsonStr += decoder.decode(data[i], { stream });
        }
      }
      
      // build json object from string.
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

      filter.write(encoder.encode(jsonStr));
      filter.close();
    };
  }
  
  browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    listener,
    { urls: ["https://example.com/jsonresource/*"], types: ["xmlhttprequest"] },
    ["blocking"],
  );
```

Ensure "webRequestBlocking" permission is included in manifest.