# How can I get all HTTP requests of a web page by using Chrome Extension API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know that I can get all HTTP Requests in DevTool, but now I want to get them in a chrome extension. Which API can do this job?

Answer (score 3):

You would be looking at [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) with an [event filter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter) based on the tab ID.

Something like this (requires `"webRequest"` permission and `"<all_urls>"` host permission):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    // Do something with the details
  },
  {tabId: /* ... */, urls: "<all_urls>"}
);
```

P.S. I saw your other question regarding resources; note that you can further filter requests by type, e.g. `"stylesheet"`

Comment: I assume this will not catch requests which happened before the listener was added? If the OP intends to use this from a page-action button, it may not yield the desired results.

Comment: @levi Technically, that's not specified in the question. But neither do DevTools (normally) log network requests until opened. You need to be ready for this.

Answer (score 0):

[chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) is helpful but it doesn't let you read the response body in Chrome. I have a solution for reading the body here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390377/1226799