# Can chrome WebRequest API monitor the http request?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, webrequest

I want to monitor all the http request send from my chrome browser, and collect all the http request to another server.

I have read [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831916/is-it-possible-to-monitor-http-traffic-in-chrome-using-an-extension) and [These examples](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webRequest.html#examples), but I don't know how to get the  content of the request.

For example, when I browse google.com in my chrome browser with this chrome extension, this extension will send the following the another server which will collect it:

```
GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: zh-CN
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: www.google.com
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: blabla...
```

I can not find how to get the content of all the requests from [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.webRequest.html#type-RequestFilter), is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it's not possible at the moment. All you can get is headers.

Comment: Maybe the only way I can do is to use [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html)

Comment: It's not possible with the WebRequest API in Chrome but there are other ways: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390377/1226799